# ANTLR4 strange behavior with a simple rule

Tags: antlr4

I a defining a simple rule in ANTLR4 for C# target below:

```
    numberliteral: NUMBER;
    NUMBER    :   '-'? INT '.' INT EXP?   // 1.35, 1.35E-9, 0.3, -4.5
                 |   '-'? INT EXP            // 1e10 -3e4
                 |   '-'? INT                // -4 12
                 ;
    fragment INT :   [0] | [1-9] [0-9]* ; // no leading zeros
    fragment EXP :   [Ee] [+\-]? INT ; // \- since - means "range" inside [...]
```

The results are weird:

1. Anything that fulfil the first alternative in NUMBER is good, e.g. 1.2, 1.2e+1, -1.2
2. The other two alternative for NUMBER only work if there is '-' sign in front of the number, e.g. -1e+2 or -2. It does not recognize positive number like: 2 or 2e+3

Anyone has any idea what goes wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: How do you know it "does not recognize" a positive number? Can you include a complete copy of your grammar?

Answer (score 0):

Did work for me (in Antlrworks NetBeans plugin):

Grammar:

```
grammar simpleGrammar;

start: numberliteral*;


numberliteral: NUMBER;
NUMBER    :   '-'? INT '.' INT EXP?   // 1.35, 1.35E-9, 0.3, -4.5
             |   '-'? INT EXP            // 1e10 -3e4
             |   '-'? INT                // -4 12
             ;
fragment INT :   [0] | [1-9] [0-9]* ; // no leading zeros
fragment EXP :   [Ee] [+\-]? INT ; // \- since - means "range" inside [...]


WS : [ \t\n\r] -> skip;
```

Sample:

```
1.35
1.35E-9
0.3
-4.5
1e10
-3e4
-4
12
```

Result:

[image: parse result]